# Android: playing a youtube video INSIDE of my application

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-webview, android-video-player

I'm hoping someone can set the record straight for me.  I know there are several posts about this issue, but I'm still unclear about this.

I want my application to show an image of a page out of a book, and inside that image I want to play a youtube video.  Apparently, I"m supposed to use a WebView for this.

```
    WebView mWebView = new WebView(this);        

    mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    mWebView.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);
    mWebView.setWebViewClient(new HelloWebViewClient());
    setContentView(mWebView);

    String Play = "<iframe width=\"600\" height=\"400\" src=\"http://www.youtube.com   /embed/VCDOjdYhj1Y\" frameborder=\"10\"</iframe>";
    mWebView.loadData(Play, "text/html", "utf-8"); 
}
    private class HelloWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;
    }
}
```

When I do this, the video looks okay but the sound is lagging.  It's very noticeable if someone is talking because the words don't match their lips.  From what I understand, WebView really isn't meant for showing video even though it's supported.  It's simply a way of showing a web page inside of the app with preferably no user interaction.  If you want video and web pages, you're supposed to launch the browser with an Intent.  I don't want to do this.  I can't use a VideoView because I'm not pointing directly to a video file.

So is that it?  Am I out of options?  You'd think Youtube and Android would be very compatible since their both Google.  Embedding a youtube video in an HTML View works really well in iPhone apps.  I hope someone can give me the final word on this.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Can't it is something with how the url is loaded like parents, etc.